# unable to lnk SCSS/CSS file to React.js file

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I am unable to link SCSS/CSS file into my React.js code, can anyone help me, below is the code

```
**import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import './SideDrawer.scss'
import Sidebar from "react-sidebar";
import SideNav,{MenuIcon} from "react-simple-sidenav";
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Menu from  'rc-menu';**
```

import './SideDrawer.scss' ---- is the file which isn't working

please help to resolve this

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: What does `isn't working` mean? Is it being loaded? No? Yes but not being used? This question is too vague as it stands

Comment: It should work if `SideDrawer.scss` is under the same folder.

Comment: Hello @surabhi. I see you are a new contributor. Please update your question with a stack trace of the error you are getting symptoms etc so we can try and help you.

Over all I syntax looks good!